# Having trouble deserializing JSON to POJO with a REST API and MongoDB

Tags: java, json, mongodb, spring-boot, deserialization

The following components are part of a Spring Boot 3.0.8 application with Java 17 and Maven.
The controller makes a request to MongoDB. POST works just fine with the current setup.

I have been trying to get the data of the list of Preferences for my UserPreferences object:

```
@Document
public class UserPreferences {
    @Id
    private Long userId;

    private List<Preference> preferences;

    public UserPreferences() {
        
    }

    public UserPreferences(Long id, List<Preference> preferences) {
        this.userId = id;
        this.preferences = preferences;
    }
//getters and setters
```

The Preference class, with jackson annotations.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes.Type;

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @Type(value = MoviePreference.class, name = "movie"),
        @Type(value = GenrePreference.class, name = "genre")
})

public abstract class Preference {

    protected Preference() {

    }

}
```

And the controller GetMapping request, which as of now doesn't work:

```
@GetMapping
    Collection<UserPreferences> allPreferences() throws JsonProcessingException {
        PolymorphicTypeValidator ptv = BasicPolymorphicTypeValidator.builder()
                .allowIfSubType("com.partytime.userpreferencesservice")
                .allowIfSubType("java.util.ArrayList")
                .build();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.activateDefaultTyping(ptv, ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL);

        String jsonDataString = mapper.writeValueAsString(repository.findAll());
        UserPreferences deserializedResponse 
        = mapper.readValue(jsonDataString, UserPreferences.class);

        //(Collection<UserPreferences>) repository.findAll();

        return deserializedResponse;
    }
```

It seems like whatever I try, it always returns the following error:

```
2023-05-28T19:41:26.719+02:00 ERROR 21124 --- [nio-8082-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [com.partytime.userpreferencesservice.models.Preference]] with root cause
```

I have tried several possible solutions. For example, I exhausted the Jackson Inheritance article written by Baeldung, looked for similar problems here on stackoverflow, but nothing seems to work. It is possible that I'm missing a crucial detail, but maybe somebody can help me fix this.

Comment: Why did your method `allPreferences()` return `UserPreferences` rather than `List<Preference>`?

Comment: @LHCHIN Hi there, thanks for pointing out my error. Yes, like I commented out before returning a string value, I originally returned a Collection(UserPreferences). I changed it for clarity.